# Subtracting columns in pandas dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

there is a dataframe with columns in which the datetime64 type is indicated.
I need to get the difference between these columns. With this subtraction,

```
data["time1"] - data["time2"]
```

Where data["time1"] and data["time2"] have the form:

```
0      2020-01-20
1      2020-01-20
2      2020-01-21
7      2020-01-21
8      2020-01-21
    ...
```

I get an array instead of the scalar for the string:

```
Out[43]: 

0       TimedeltaIndex(['17 days', '17 days', '18 days...
1       TimedeltaIndex([ '5 days',  '5 days',  '6 days...
2       TimedeltaIndex(['16 days', '16 days', '17 days...
7       TimedeltaIndex([ '6 days',  '6 days',  '7 days...
8       TimedeltaIndex(['11 days', '11 days', '12 days...
```

how to subtract 2 columns element by element?

Comment: `data['time1'] - data['time2']` does indeed subtract element by element. What do you have in `time1` and `time2`?

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong. 
The fact is that in data ["time1"]:

```
0      2020-01-20
1      2020-01-20
2      2020-01-21
7      2020-01-21
8      2020-01-21
...
Length: 533, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

and in ["time2"]:

```
0       2020-01-03 00:00:00
1       2020-01-15 00:00:00
2       2020-01-04 00:00:00
7       2020-01-14 00:00:00
8       2020-01-09 00:00:00
9       2020-01-16 00:00:00
...
Length: 533, dtype: object
```